# Understanding structure / syntax of nested annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I came across following spring hibernate annotations:

```
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "@HQL_GET_ALL_ADDRESS", query = "from Address") })
@NamedNativeQueries({ @NamedNativeQuery(name = "@SQL_GET_ALL_ADDRESS", query = "select emp_id, address_line1, city, zipcode from
Address") })
```

I found it difficult to understand the structure /syntax of the annotation. What kind of nesting of properties does these annotations follow? Is it spring expression language? I tried to go through [spring expression language documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) and I am still not able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four annotations at play in your sample code: `@NamedQueries` + `@NamedQuery` and `@NamedNativeQueries` + `@NamedNativeQuery`.

Hibernate provides them extending directly from the [Java Persitence API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) (JPA) ones.

```java
@NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name = "@HQL_GET_ALL_ADDRESS", query = "from Address")
})
@NamedNativeQueries({
   @NamedNativeQuery(name = "@SQL_GET_ALL_ADDRESS", query = "select emp_id, address_line1, city, zipcode from Address")
})
```

I think your confusion comes from the fact that the names of both queries start with a `@` like in `@HQL_GET_ALL_ADDRESS` but that's not a requirement at all. You can name your query `bob` if you like.

Other than that, as the name suggest, you can define multiple `@NamedQuery` inside of a `@NamedQueries` and the same goes for `@NamedNativeQueries`.

```java
@NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name = "get_all_address", query = "from Address"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "get_all_active_address", query = "from Address where active = true")
})
```

Hibernate documentation about named queries can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api-named-query-example).

To expand a bit on the curly braces inside java annotations, they just mean that you can supply an array of objects instead of a single one. Think of it as if you were initializing a new array like this:

```java
String[] items = {"one", "two", "three"};
```

So you supply an array to the annotation. In this particular case, it just so happens that `@NamedQueries` expects an array of other annotations. This is probably more clear if you check the source code for `@NamedQueries`:

```java
...
public @interface NamedQueries { 

    /** (Required) An array of <code>NamedQuery</code> annotations. */
     NamedQuery [] value (); 
}
```

It's standard Java annotation syntax, you can see a reference with examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html).

Comment: So, those `@HQL` and `@SQL` prefixes are simply not necessary? and also I was confused by the syntax. But those are following standard java annotations syntax right? If yes, can you please point me to java docs explaining annotations, especially curly braces inside annotations and annotation inside annotation (`@NamedQuery` inside `@NamedQueries`)?

Comment: Yes, it's standard annotation syntax. The curly braces just mean that you can supply an array. I have updated my answer with more info and links.